# Typescript: require param when another is required

Tags: typescript

I have an interface where the `c` param should only be required when the `a` one is `true`.

```
interface IArgs {
  a: boolean,
  b: string,
  c: string
}
```

The below seems to work but how do I omit the `c` param in the first clause? Used `type` since an `interface` would return an error.

```
type TArgs = {
  a: true,
  b: string,
  c?: string
} | {
  a: false,
  b: string,
  c: string
};
```

Comment: `c?: never` or `c?: undefined` are the closest you can get I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be what you re looking for. But you would have to explicitly set `TArgs<true>`

```
type TArgs<T extends boolean> = {
   a: T,
   b: string,
   c: T extends true ? string : null
 }
```

Example of how it could look with a factory function:

```
type TArgs<T extends true | false> = {
    a: T,
    c?: T extends true ? string : null
}

const argsFactory = <T extends boolean>(a: T, c: T extends true ? string : null): TArgs<T> => {
    return {
        a,
        c
    }
}

// Works
argsFactory(true, "string");
argsFactory(false, null);

// Doesnt Work
argsFactory(false, "some String");
argsFactory(true, null)
```